# listview state undefined

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/settings_unpressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/settings_unpressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/settings_unpressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/settings_unpressed" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

I have a listView which has a rounded corner, when I try scroll my listView the borders become sharped (like rectangle). Could anyone tell me how called state when we scroll listView. I use code in above but no result, maybe I should have another state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
set `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` and `android:scrollingCache="false"` that't it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in that way. You need to have different drawable resources for the top item, middle item, bottom item and in case the list has just 1 item. 
Then in your custom adapter, you need to change your getView in something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //...

   if (position == 0 && entry_list.size() == 1) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner);
        } else if (position == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner_top);
        } else if (position == entry_list.size() - 1) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner_bottom);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_middle);
        }

       //...
   }
```

Check this [tutorial](http://blog.synyx.de/2011/11/android-listview-with-rounded-corners/), it is easy and very well done.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background of the listView as a rounded-cornered drawable and then for every row item leave some margin. This the entire content of the listview lies within a rounded-cornered view